# Как сделать выплывающий текст из-под заголовка при нажатии?

Tags: html, css, jquery, анимация, текст

У меня есть что-то вроде меню. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на элемент в меню из-под него выплывал текст (плавно). Я сделал так, чтобы текст появлялся резко, но меня это не устраивает и вообще мне кажется я сделал все как-то чересчур коряво. Как можно сделать все красивее и плавнее?

```
Код: https://codepen.io/Psoriaz/pen/abWOQdX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, у JQuery есть готовые эффекты [.slideDown](https://api.jquery.com/slidedown/), [.slideUp](https://api.jquery.com/slideup/), [.slideToggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/), реализующие то, что вам нужно:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('div').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>

<div hidden>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultricies lectus eu feugiat tempus. Aenean nec tempor mauris. Aliquam sollicitudin pharetra dolor, in lobortis massa pharetra nec. Morbi porttitor diam id eros ullamcorper iaculis. Nulla vitae neque egestas, molestie sem non, luctus erat. Sed efficitur sem vel erat tincidunt, at luctus elit vestibulum. Cras ut dictum velit, vel pulvinar diam. Donec sed elit dolor. Integer at ex vestibulum, ultricies dolor vel, tincidunt libero.</div>
```